# Problems with using float "possible lossy conversion"

Tags: java, floating-point

This is a code I've written for one of my CS classes, but I guess I dont have a proper understanding of the term float yet. It works for the first 3 conversions, and then it gives me error for pints, quarts and gallons (where decimals start). I've tried converting them into fractions but the program just ends up spitting out 0 as the result then. The error that results is incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float

My code is as  follows:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

/* 
Description: This application will be used to convert a user given volume 
in cups to its equivalent number of teaspoons, tablespoons, ounces, pints
quarts, or gallons.

This program will allow us to view what a certain volume of cups would be in
tablespoons, teaspoons etc.

This program will need the number of cups from the user.
Then the program will output the neccessary teaspoons, tablespoons etc.

                    4 cups equals 4 * 48 = 192 teaspoons
                    4 cups equals 4 * 16 =  64 tablespoons
                    4 cups equals 4 * 8   =  32 ounces
                    4 cups equals 4 * 0.5   =  2 pints
                    4 cups equals 4 * 0.25   =  1 quart
                    4 cups equals 4 * 0.0625   =   0.2500 gallon

java.util and java.text will be used

The input and output will be simple text based interactions using 
system.out.Println and scanner

Psuedocode: 
            Output a welcome message
            Output a message that describes what the program will do
            Output a message requesting the number cups the user wishes to 
            convert

            read the input value and store it

            calculate the teaspoons, tablespoons etc and store it.

            output a message that displays this values so the user can see
            it
*/

class cupsconversion
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println("Welcome to Shahrukhs Cup Conversion Program");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("This application will be used to convert a user given volume");
System.out.println("in cups to its equivalent number of teaspoons, tablespoons, ounces, pints");
System.out.println("quarts, or gallons");
System.out.println("\n \n");
System.out.println("Please type in a +ve real value for the number of cups you want converted");
System.out.print(" Number of cups = ");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

float cups; // We are storing the input the user puts in float.

cups = input.nextFloat();

float teaspoons = cups * 48;

float tablespoons = cups * 16;

float ounces = cups * 8;

float pints = cups * 0*5;

float quarts = cups * 0.25;

float gallons = cups * 0.0625;

System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in teaspoons are " + teaspoons);
System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in tablespoons are " + tablespoons);
System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in ounces are " + ounces); 
System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in pints are " + pints);   
System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in quarts are " + quarts);
System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in gallons are " + gallons);

}

}
```

Comment: add your input, the output you got, and the expected output

Comment: `0.5F` instead of `0*5` is it not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float quarts = cups * 0.25;
```

Here `0.25` is interpreted as a `double`, forcing `cups * 0.25` to be represented as a `double`, which has higher precision than `cups`.  You have several options:

- write `cups * 0.25f`
- write `cups / 4`
- write `(float) (cups * 0.25)`

Also, note that you wrote `cups * 0*5;` instead of `cups * 0.5`, which will set `cups` to `0`.

Comment: A much more in-depth reading of how floating point arithmetic works is  http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

/* 
 Description: This application will be used to convert a user given volume 
 in cups to its equivalent number of teaspoons, tablespoons, ounces, pints
 quarts, or gallons.

This program will allow us to view what a certain volume of cups would be in
tablespoons, teaspoons etc.

This program will need the number of cups from the user.
Then the program will output the neccessary teaspoons, tablespoons etc.

                4 cups equals 4 * 48 = 192 teaspoons
                4 cups equals 4 * 16 =  64 tablespoons
                4 cups equals 4 * 8   =  32 ounces
                4 cups equals 4 * 0.5   =  2 pints
                4 cups equals 4 * 0.25   =  1 quart
                4 cups equals 4 * 0.0625   =   0.2500 gallon

java.util and java.text will be used

The input and output will be simple text based interactions using 
system.out.Println and scanner

Psuedocode: 
        Output a welcome message
        Output a message that describes what the program will do
        Output a message requesting the number cups the user wishes to 
        convert

        read the input value and store it

        calculate the teaspoons, tablespoons etc and store it.

        output a message that displays this values so the user can see
        it
*/

public class cupsconversion
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println("Welcome to Shahrukhs Cup Conversion Program");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("This application will be used to convert a user given              volume");
  System.out.println("in cups to its equivalent number of teaspoons,     tablespoons, ounces, pints");
 System.out.println("quarts, or gallons");
 System.out.println("\n \n");
 System.out.println("Please type in a +ve real value for the number of cups you want converted");
 System.out.print(" Number of cups = ");

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

 float cups; // We are storing the input the user puts in float.

 cups = input.nextFloat();

float teaspoons = cups * 48;

float tablespoons = cups * 16;

float ounces = cups * 8;

float pints = cups * 0*5;

float quarts = cups * 0.25f;

float gallons = cups * 0.0625f;

  System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in teaspoons are " + teaspoons);
  System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in tablespoons are " + tablespoons);
  System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in ounces are " + ounces); 
  System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in pints are " + pints);   
  System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in quarts are " + quarts);
  System.out.println(" Given " + cups + " cups, the volume in gallons are " +     gallons);

 }

     } //fractions needs to be followed with "f"
      //float quarts = cups * 0.25f;
     //float gallons = cups * 0.0625f;
    // or you will need to cast to convert from double to float
   //float quarts = (float) (cups * 0.25);
  //float gallons = (float) (cups * 0.0625);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you type a decimal number as 0.25, its interpreted as a double.As a float is less precise than a double, the conversion cannot be performed implicitly.

If you want to create a float, you should end your number with f (i.e.: 0.25f).

For more explanation, see the primitive data types definition of the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

That's a warning, not an error. Double is typically 64 bits and float typically 32 bits, so you're losing the bottom 32 bits in that conversion (it's a little more complicated than that due to the formats involved, but that's a reasonable approximation). Really not a problem unless you're dealing with numbers which are not expressible as floats, i.e. really huge, really tiny, or big with a small fraction.

You rarely want to use float unless you are having problems with the memory usage, so just saying "double" - short for "double-precision floating point" - should be fine.

When you say "fractions", you haven't explained what you mean there but I presume you are using notation like 3/4. If you provide two integers, as you have here, you will get an integer result, because that's actually a useful thing to do for some programming purposes. The notation for a floating-point expression of an integer is to add ".0" to the end, eg. 3.0/4.0.